# MySQL statement to fetch rows between unix timestamps

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I have a problem with fetching required rows from MySQL table correctly within date interval.

My table has had such structure originally (yes with unixtimestamps not mysql dates):

```
    id    name    departures                   depmin         depmax 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1      a      1327608000                 1327608000     1327608000

    2      b   1321646400,1322856000,        1321646400     1337976000
               1325880000,1327694400,
               1329508800,1330718400,
               1331928000,1332532800,
               1333137600,1333742400,
               1334347200,1334952000,
               1336161600,1336766400,
               1337371200,1337976000

    3      c   1315166400,1316894400,        1315166400    1327780800
               1317758400,1318968000,
               1319918400,1320004800,
               1320091200,1320177600,
               1321387200,1324152000,
               1325448000,1325534400,
               1325620800,1327780800
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My task is to get all 3 rows with departure between 1327536001 and 1327881601 but if I query like so:

```
SELECT * FROM exampletable WHERE depmin >= 1327536001 AND depmax <= 1327881601
```

I only get the first row (with id 1 and name a). So I'm totally confused how to get all three rows between this example interval?

Please advise how to construct my where query or how to reformat the table.

Comment: Well, the other two rows are not exactly in this interval - at best they're overlapping.

Comment: They are. Look the `departure` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to get all the `id`'s where *any* timestamps from column `departures` fall within specific interval.

Unfortunally, there is no simple way to achieve that. You'll have to either write an extensive stored procedure/function (involving parsing string from `departures` column, putting results in array variable or temporary table, comparing them to your borders etc.) or you'll have to redesign your database heavily.

Personally, I'd suggest to move data from `departures` column into separate table, one departure time per row, like this:

```
   id            departure
------------------------------
    1        1327608000
    2        1321646400
    2        1322856000
...
```

Then you will be able to satisfy your original requirements with query like

```
SELECT * FROM exampletable WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM departures WHERE departure >= 1327536001 AND departure <= 1327881601)
```

Answer (score 2):

You would get all 3 rows returned if the depmin values for the b and c were actually greater than 1327536001.  Looks like a data issue.  The SQL query looks good to me.

Answer (score 2):

You get perfectly valid result, the first row is the only one with depmin greater than or equal 1327536001 and depmax less than or equal 1327881601. If you only want to limit `depmin` or only `depmax`, ask for it.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your 4 table records like this:

```
1. depmin: 1327608000
   query:  1327536001      depmin >= query -> TRUE

   depmax: 1327608000
   query : 1327881601      depmax <= query -> TRUE

TRUE and TRUE -> TRUE

2. depmin: 1321646400
   query : 1327536001      depmin >= query -> FALSE

   depmax: 1337976000
   query : 1327881601      depmax <= query -> FALSE

FALSE and FALSE -> FALSe
```

If, if I'm reading your question right, you're just trying to find any rows where the query timestamp ranges overlap the database table timestamps, then your logic should actually be:

```
WHERE depmax >= 1327536001 AND depmin <= 1327881601
      ^^^^^^----- reversed ----^^^^^^
```

That way you'll get ANY record where its min/max values fall within the bounds of your query's ranges.

Comment: Yes, that's right for my question. Thank you. But I can't obviously show the right example based on my production table data where I still have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to swap `depmin` and `depmax` in your query condition.

That will mean "intervals having intersection with [1327536001 ... 1327881601]"